# SwiftUI - TextField fails to update variables from @EnviromentObject

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have @ObservableObject with @Published var inside, which I want to update by TextFields in another view PizzaCalc(). I am using @EnviromentObject to pass this var to PizzaCalc(). I am using @EnviromentObject because this var will be used in more views.

PizzaCalc() gets the initial values, but it appears that TextFields inside it doesn't update the values. I tried using @ObservedObject instead, but results are similar.
This is my very first project in SwiftUI. Any help will be really appreciated!

Current state of my code:

```
//custom data model
struct Pizza: Identifiable {
    @State var id = UUID()
    @State public var name: String
    @State public var diameter: String
    @State public var price: String
    @State public var pieces: String
    @State public var no: String
}

//ObservaleObject I want to update using TextFields from PizzaCalc()
class PizzaList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var menu: [Pizza] = []
    
//initial values
    init(){
    menu = [
           Pizza(name: "", diameter: "", price: "", pieces: "", no: "1"),
           Pizza(name: "", diameter: "", price: "", pieces: "", no: "2"),
           Pizza(name: "", diameter: "", price: "", pieces: "", no: "3"),
           Pizza(name: "", diameter: "", price: "", pieces: "", no: "4")
           ]
          }
                                     }

struct TabBar: View {
    
    @StateObject var pizzaList: PizzaList = PizzaList()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            PizzaCalc().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "circle.circle")
                Text("Pizza")
            }
//other views here
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .environmentObject(pizzaList)
    }

//struct where I want to update values
struct PizzaCalc: View {
 
    @EnvironmentObject var pizzaList: PizzaList

var body: some View {
        
    VStack {
        NavigationView {
    
            List {
                    
                ForEach(pizzaList.menu) { pizza in
                        
                    Text("Pizza \(pizza.no)")
                        .font(.title)
                    TextField("Name", text: pizza.$name)
//Text below for testing if the value updates
                    Text(pizza.name)
                    TextField("Diameter", text: pizza.$diameter)
                    TextField("Pcs", text: pizza.$pieces)
                    TextField("Price", text: pizza.$price)
                            }
               
            }
```

Comment: Your code is working fine, at least when I try to reproduce it without the tab view and the PizzaCalc View having a StateObject instead of EnvironmentObject

Comment: `@State` is for use inside a `View` -- not your model. You should remove that annotation from all of `Pizza`'s properties.

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)